# Why do I get the Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. only for my HTC One X and not Nexus 5X?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am a beginner in Android Programming. I was trying create a fitness tracker app using the DetectedActivity Google API library. My program was working fine in the emulator( I have used Nexus 5X for this). However, when I tried running the same on my mobile(HTC One X), I got the following error. I have tried cleaning the project which yielded no errors in build. But, I keep getting this error whenever I run it in my phone.Can anyone throw some light on this problem?

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Comment: you are crossing max method limit for a dex file, you have to enable [Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: Thank You Saurabh.

Comment: I have resolved that issue thanks to your help. But, I have got another problem. My app in the phone stops working without even starting. Do you know what causes this behavior?